# What did he say in this video ( 1:45- 1:55)

Tags: meaning, listening

He said " It's perfect, we have so many people wanna to get on rage with you. In a play of you two if you just put your headphones." I am not 100% he is saying the last words IN a play of you too ? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIgNHUMzKbA&t=124s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s sounds like he said “and play a few two/too” before proceeding to play the recordings.

> It’s perfect! We’ve had so many people who want to get on RAGE with you. And play a few two/too, you just ... you might want to put those headphones on.

Comment: what’s the meaning of that - and play a few two?

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby I’d assume he means he’s going to play a few recordings for the other guy to listen to.

Comment: ok thanks mate, so few two means few recordings , quite strange I couldn’t  catch that !

Comment: "play a few too." And I think "rage" should be capitalized as the abbreviated name of a show.

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby No problem, you’re welcome!

Comment: @JeffMorrow oops, I thought I heard ‘two’, do you want to post an answer too?

Comment: And what I hear is "I'munna [*=I'm going to] play a few, too .." -- that is, a few of the calls the show has received.

Comment: There's no way to hear a difference between "to", "too" and "two".  I assume that he says "It's perfect.  We've had so many people wanting to get on Rage today with you.  And I'll play a few, too, if you just . . . you wouldn't mind putting those headphones on.  Um, well, um . . . we'll play the first one here."  That's not quite what I hear, since I'm not accustomed to his accent, but it is something that makes sense in context.

Comment: @ Panda No problem. "Two" and "too" are homonyms. Trying to decipher that horrible English is not something on which I care to give formal answers.